# Matplotlib contour: set range of colorbar (not range of colormap)

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have a problem with the colorbar for contour plots with user-defined levels. As you can see in the figure below, the color for the highest level (red) is not shown well in the colorbar. To solve this, I would like to change the range of the colorbar (e.g. from 0 to 1), while not changing the contour levels or range of the colormap.

So far, I have tried to manually set the ticks of the colorbar in the colorbar-call, but that doesn't change the range. (That is, ticks outside 0.3-0.8 will just not show up)

Minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.random.rand(10,10)
im = plt.contour(z, levels = [0.3,0.5,0.8], cmap="rainbow")
plt.colorbar(im)
```

[image: contour plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to change the range of the colorbar (e.g. from 0 to 1)

[image]

Save the colorbar object, change its boundaries and the ticks' position, finally update the plot to reflect our wishes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.random.rand(10,10)
im = plt.contour(z, levels = [0.3,0.5,0.8], cmap="rainbow")
cb = plt.colorbar(im)
cb.boundaries = np.array((0.0, 0.5, 1.0))
cb.set_ticks((0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 1))
cb.update_normal(im)
```